# Update old app on itunes connect with Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, app-store-connect

Didn't find any information on this while googling. So I'll ask it here myself.

I am currently working on rebuilding an app that is 4-5 years old, written in Objective-C. I am coding in swift for the updated version of the app.

How will I be able to update the current app on itunes connect? Is it enough to just change the Bundle identifier in the project to the same as the old one?

Or do I have to create the swift files within the old project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, making sure the bundle identifier is the same is the important part. Also, you have to increase the version number in order to be able to upload an updated version of your app.

Just create a new project and recode everything in Swift.

Comment: Ok, so just the same bundle identifier when I create a new project and it will work fine when I upload? :) no need to change some building settings or trying to link with the other project?

Comment: Yes. That is what the answer says. You can just copy over stuff you need, such as assets (e.g. images).

Comment: Be sure to test well. When I ran my app in release mode it silently exited when nil was found. I submitted a bug report for that.

Answer (score 3):

The bundle identifier is the main thing. However, if you write settings to user defaults or files to the documents directory or other directories, you need to make sure that those settings work properly in the old version, or that it's ok to ignore them in the new version.

You should be able to test running the old app store version on a device, then installing the updated version (either from Xcode or from iTunes) and making sure the upgrade process works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Apps are identified via their IDs and verified with their signings. So long as you use the same development certs, signing, provisioning, and application ID you should be able to change the application however you like and still be able to identify it correctly.